# Applying z-index to an image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I'm trying to display an image through my home page in WordPress. I can display it through css, through a widget, but not by adding it as code to my home page.

I've tried applying z-index, as I have an element which displays text images in that section, but nothing will display.

Image html

```
<div class="fbfp"><img src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IMG_20200601_134623-300x279.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="279" class="size-medium wp-image-16023" /></div>
```

And html controlling homepage.

```
<section class="content- 
area  pt0 "><div id="main" 
class="" role="main">
<div 
id="shapely_home_parallax- 
 2" class="widget 
shapely_home_parallax">      
<section class="cover 
fullscreen image-bg">
<div class="parallax-window 
fullscreen" data- 
parallax="scroll" data- 
image- 
src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-  
content/uploads/2019/0
8/download-2.png" data-ios- 
fix="true" data-over- 
scroll-fix="true" data- 
android-fix="true">
<div class="align- 
transform">
<div class="row">
<div class="top-parallax- 
section">
```

Page [here](https://4309.co.uk)

It should be straight forward in WordPress because you just add the code to the text editor on the page.

Css

```
.fbfp {position:relative; bottom:300px;z-index: 100;}
```

`parallax-window` is the operative part here I think.

Comment: Can't see this image in the code of your page, HTML

Comment: Updated code here and on site and republished. Now?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. there is on IMG_20200601_134623-300x279.jpg in your code.

Comment: There should be. I've just published it but it won't display. Why not?

Comment: Refreshed the page, the page, tried different browser - still not there

Comment: It should be mentioned twice. One on defunct css`. change .bluedot1 {height: 1150px; width: 1150px; border-radius: 20px;background-image: url(http://4309.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IMG_20200601_134623.jpg); background-size: cover; margin-top: -800px;opacity: 0.5;}` and once as an upload in homepage.

Comment: Yeah. How odd. Unless my something in my php has broken.

Comment: I can see a css code. But not <img>. Should it be on a home page?

Comment: Yep.............

Comment: Anyway, i will try to answer.

Comment: The only other thing i can think of is that when i press `publish` it doesn't actually publish. Where would i find source code for this function?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, `z-index` only works with element with `position:` `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative`, and `sticky`, I suppose.

Add to your CSS

```
.fbfp /*or '.fbfp img' */ {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 9999; /* or any your value*/ 
}
```

Remember. If any parent element of your image also has `z-index` - it will be stronger and 
decisive around other elements with `z-index` on it's level.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah. Applied z-index 9999 but didn't work. I'm wondering if something else could be obscuring it because on the other pages it's fine.